# Merging values with same row names

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a table like:

```
   Genes     Category
1. Gene1     dark_11
2. Gene1     dark_9
3. Gene2     dark_7
4. Gene1     dark_5
```

I want to merge the `Category` values separated by comma with same row name in the `Genes` column to get the output like:

```
   Genes      Category
1. Gene1      dark_11, dark_9, dark_5
2. Gene2      dark_7
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are the line numbers actually there, or are they for illustration purposes only? How is the file separated, tab, space or fixed-width?

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk arrays indexed by the condition to be met, and then append to each value of the array each category associated, for example:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0}; NR>1 {if(cat[$2])cat[$2]=cat[$2]", "$3; else cat[$2]=$3;}; END{j=1; for (i in cat) print j++".", i, cat[i]}' test.txt
```

being `test.txt` your input file.

The `cat` array would contain the two values, `cat[GeneX]` which will contain a string with the categories concatenated for each gene. Note that before adding a category to the correct value of the array you have to check if the array is empty or not, just to add the comma between categories.